# Why is there a difference in panning inertia between Google Maps API examples and Google Maps site?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building out a map component in React and noticed that the panning inertia between my component and Google Maps is a bit different. e.g., in my React component, if the user drags the map a bit and lets the mouse button go off, the movement decelerates rather quickly.

However, if you go to Google Maps and do the same thing, there's quite a bit more movement the happens after the user releases the mouse button. Interestingly, I noticed the same behavior between the official Google Maps API examples and Google Maps.

API docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction

If you pan on one of the examples, the movement quickly stops.

I've been unable to find anything in the official API docs -- is there a way to change how inertia behaves with the Google Maps JavaScript API so that it more closely matches what happens on maps.google.com? Or is this just how the API behaves?

Comment: Google Maps website ≠ Google Maps API. Just don't expect the same behavior/functionality between the two. Seems like there's a kind of "easing out" effect on Google Maps that you don't get with the API, but afaik there is nothing you can do about it in the API.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Ah, that makes sense. Feel free to make this reply an actual answer and I'll mark it as such.